# Angular Shepherd Sample Required for Tour Guide

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular9, angular10

I have to develop a UI Tour for my Angular Application and I saw the package angular-shepherd for it (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-shepherd)

I am unable to follow the documentation properly regarding how to implement it. If possible,is there any demo Application code available online which has implemented this package for a virtual tour before? I would be highly thankful if someone can share resources to learn to implement it or any code for reference. I am finding it difficult to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented overall shepherd example on my GitHub. Try using, That might help you.

GitHub link : https://github.com/amitgandole/Angular-ShepherdJS-Example

Comment if you need more help.